# android game using bullet and libgdx

Tags: opengl, 3d, android, bullet-physics

i'm developing a android project for school and i'm currently using libgdx for rendering. It performs quite well, but it lacks a 3d physics library. So i searched and found that Bullet physics engine was ported to android through NDK (c++). Did anyone try to connect this two libs together?

I've never used a physics engine/library before (i've mainly developed 2d games so i've made one my self) and wanted to ask if any one had any previous experiences with implementing bullet and libgdx? To be more precise i need to simulate a jump and implement physics like: wind/drag, friction, lift, gravity; during the jump.

Does bullet calculate the gravity and other forces by it self (if so can i implement other forces easily?) or can i control which element gets updated (mainly re transformed) and when? How does collision detection work (is there some kind of collision world/collection)? Can i handle collision detection on my own or does bullet take care of this as well?

Thanks for the reply's!

Answer (score 2):

I believe libgdx team is [in the middle of including bullet into libgdx.](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/issues/detail?id=298) But as they mentioned, I am not sure when it will be done. I think this answers your first question.

For the second part of questions, I am not an expert on bullet engine, but it's called physics engine so like box2d, the main physics operation should be taken care of by itself and user can customize it with callbacks. And Update might occur after [stepping.](http://www.bulletphysics.org/mediawiki-1.5.8/index.php/Stepping_the_World) Please check [its documentation for sure.](http://www.bulletphysics.org/mediawiki-1.5.8/index.php?title=Documentation)